Azure Logic app APIM connector retry when Retry is set to None
We have a logic app that uses APIM to call a backend API to create records using a POST request. We discovered some of the records that are created in backend is duplicated. when we looked deep into the issue we can see there is only one request from logic app to the APIM. To call APIM we use APIM connector and in the action Retry policy is set to None.
But, when we checked the Azure APIM logs we can see there are two requests around same time and one of them has been failed with Response code 0 "Client connection was unexpectedly closed". We Can't figure out what triggers the second request in APIM since the retry is set to None in logic app. And in the backend side logs we have both requests coming in.
We are expecting to have a error in logic app when it fails to communicate to the backend.
this is the JSON Payload
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "caller": {
        "clientId": "SIMREFNSW2"
      },
      "shipper": {
        "clientId": "SPECSOL"
      },
      "consignee": {
        "clientId": "1996DAN"
      },
      "details": [
        {
          "commodity": "FRPPLT",
          "description": "Frozen",
          "volume": 18,
          "pieces": 16,
          "weight": 9907,
          "pallets": 9,
          "piecesUnits": "QTY",
          "volumeUnits": "PLT",
          "weightUnits": "KG",
          "palletUnits": "PLS",
          "temperatureControlled": "True",
          "temperatureUnits": "C"
        }
      ],
      "traceNumbers": [
        {
          "traceType": "C",
          "traceNumber": "PICK0002",
          "user2": "1",
          "user3": "2"
        },
        {
          "traceType": "P",
          "traceNumber": "889926"
        }
      ],
      "pickUpBy": "2024-07-29T13:15:00",
      "pickUpByEnd": "2024-07-29T13:15:00",
      "deliverBy": "2024-08-02T00:00:00",
      "deliverByEnd": "2024-08-02T00:00:00",
      "serviceLevel": "RL",
      "siteId": "SITE6",
      "xrefcode": {
        "consigneeid": "1996d",
        "shipperid": "spec001",
        "otherContactId": "simua"
      },
      "userFields": {
        "user2": "PICK0002",
        "user10": "0"
      }
    }
  ]
}


Hi! Could you please share the JSON payload for the HTTP POST action here? Also, is this for a Logic App in consumption or standard mode? Additionally, could you provide a screenshot of the action's history? Thank you!

Hi, @Dieter added the payload to the question. This is a standard logic app. I don't think the issue is with the payload because if I run the same again it will work without any issue.

Following points might cause the issue-

As you are calling APIM from logic app then you need to check how many times your logic app is fired in trigger history.



We get this Client connection was unexpectedly closed error when there is any network issue in client site which is here logic app. I would suggest you to check the records creation by using a manual Http trigger if you are using a recurrence trigger currently.

